# Process-specific data in kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, system-calls

Say I have some process calling file device operation like read. Before this read the process also called a syscall(defined by me), providing me with some information relevant to the read(and possibly other future reads done by this process). What is the best way of achieving this sort of information flow in the kernel? Is there any good way to store process-specific information other than making some pid-indexed list?

I'd like the syscall information stored in kernel to be inherited by children of that process too. Would it be possible to achieve that without (somehow) traversing the process child-parent tree(and that wouldn't give me the inheritance I want because after forking I don't want changes in parent to affect the child)?

Comment: I don't want to associate PIDs with files. I want to process the file according to the specific information stored about the calling process. Then possibly process another file with same information - if opened by same process.

Comment: But that's the other way around. I want to access the data while reading, and put the data in during a syscall - the file may not even be open at that time. I want something process-specific, not file-specific.

Comment: Ok, your description is rather nebulous to me; you don't indicate the `syscall` is done before `open`, etc.  It sounds like [Security credentials](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/credentials.txt).  I think you might be a little more specific about what you want to achieve.  What kind of information is it?

Comment: See: [ask].  Especially, *If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer.* I am sure you understand your problem. I hope you can see how other people reading your question might be confused?

Comment: Hopefully this is less vague; for example, for every read a process does, I want first X chars printed to logs, where X is defined by a syscall: 1. Process calls the syscall, setting X. 2. Process calls read on an already open file or a newly opened file and magically X first chars are printed to log. After that, process forks and his clone's reads are also logged in a same way. I need a way to reach that X put somewhere by syscall when I am inside the kernel device driver module.

Comment: Typically, information is associated with files or devices. Why do you think it must be associated with a process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like we have init_task variable which gives the starting address of the runqueue and which can be accessible anywhere in the user as well as kernel space, you can add a variable which will be set to the appropriate value by your system call and then accessed by your read(appropriate) methods.